# Graph API Not returning all "Photos of you"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My app was getting the photos that a user was tagged in by calling:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[UID]/photos?fields=picture&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

It would return all the photos. Now with no change of code, it's only returning 9 photos and there should be about 255 in my account.  There is no paging information returned (next, previous) etc.

I've noticed the 2.5 API has been released recently, but I've tried in the Graph Explorer with each version of the API and the same result.

I have also checked that the `user_photos` permission exists.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're having the `user_photos` permission in the access token?

Comment: I forgot to mention that.  Yes I do.  I've even checked with /me/permissions

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/[AUTH_TOKEN]` is never a valid Graph API endpoint. Access tokens should be appended as request parameters or form fields.

Comment: Thanks derabbink.  I made an error when I was writing the post.  I am doing that in my code.   Thanks for pointing it out!!!